# How to deny an image's path for a specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My website has a folder called uploads and inside there is a folder for each client.
My question is, what's the best practice to deny the user A to see the uploads from user B?

Comment: Do you want to allow/block particular users to see those path?

Comment: More or less. I want to deny user to see what he doesn't upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with web.config changes. See documentation here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815151

Basically your web.config will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="uploads/UserA">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="UserA"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="uploads/UserB">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="UserB"/>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Nice, but in my case, the folder name is not static. It's like if only the user which upload the file could see it.

Comment: If clients are added programmatically this wouldn't work without redeploying the config for each new client.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at using an HttpHandler to intercept the request and generate a 403 (or whatever you want to do) if the user is not authorized to access the requested path.

Alternatively, you could put the logic in Global.asax in the BeginRequest method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NTFS permissions on the folders, forcing the user to authenticate. I did this for a website in 2000. Although in this case that's like using a cannon to kill a mosquito.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you might have something like following data-structure:
You may write a file name to database column. 
So you may add a column called "Allow-Anonymous" with True/False.

Now while accessing your content from server, check the db table,
If `Allow-Anonymous` is `False` and `Visiting-User` is other then `owner` then deny page display. Otherwise you may show the content.

```
DataBase mock:
Id   Data    Path             OwnerId     AllowAnonymous    Status
1    Data-A  ~/upload/Data-A  1           False             True
```

Code mock:

```
if(AllowAnonymous == True && UserId == OwnerId && Status == True)
  // Show data on page
else
  // Redirect to deny page
```

Comment: But I need to block when someone access the url path, so he doesn't pass in an controller nor any other code(maybe a handler?).